# WPF MVVM and Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I am trying to create a WPF application taking advantage of Commands but I am having an issue with commands enabling menu buttons. I am doing some simple validation, in this case, the "Save" button is disabled until the user creates a new document or loads an existing one.

Lets say my View Model looks like this where the object ViewModel inherits INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    New = new RelayCommand( OnNew, CanNew );
    Save = new RelayCommand( OnSave, CanSave );
}

ICommand m_cmdNew;

public ICommand New
{
    get { return m_cmdNew; }
    set
    {
        m_cmdNew = value;
        OnPropertyChanged( "New" );
    }
}

void OnNew( object param )
{
    bCanSave = true;
    // I read that this could resolve my problem.
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}

bool CanNew(  object param )
{
    return true;
}
```

Lets assume I am doing the same thing for a "Save" Command as well, the only exception being the "CanSave" looks like this:

```
bool CanSave( object param )
{
    return bCanSave;
}
```

My Xaml:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Text">
        <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding New}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding Save}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The problem that I am having is that the CanSave method is never called after I change the variable "bCanSave". How can I accomplish this?  I know I can simply create a property and using INotifyPropertyChanged and XAML binding, I can simply toggle the IsEnabled property, but that seems like a lot of work when from what I read, commands already do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise the [`CanExecuteChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx) event on the command you want reevaluated, in this case that should be done when that horrible hungarian bool changes.

(I would recommend making the command fields `readonly` and the properties `get`-only, commands don't usually change)